# How I can get async_connect using boost asio library?

Tags: c++, boost

I am a starter with boost library and now creating TCP async client using boost asio library functions.

I am going to implement `connect` function using `async_connect`, but it seems not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class tcp_async_client: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_async_client>
{
    tcp::socket m_socket;
    tcp::resolver m_resolver;

public:
    tcp_async_client(const tcp_async_client&) = delete;
    tcp_async_client& operator=(const tcp_async_client&) = delete;

    tcp_async_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_socket(tcp::socket(io_service)),
          m_resolver(tcp::resolver(io_service)) {}

    void start_connect(string addr, string port)
    {
        cout << "try to connect to " << addr << ":" << port << endl;

        tcp::resolver::query query(addr, port);
        boost::asio::async_connect(m_socket, m_resolver.resolve(query),
                boost::bind(&tcp_async_client::handle_connect, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void stop()
    {
        m_socket.close();
    }

private:
    // connect handler
    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            cout << "failed to connect with err: " << ec.message() << endl;
            return;
        }

        cout << "success to connect";
    }
};

// main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Usage: async_connect <addr> <port>" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    auto stp = boost::make_shared<tcp_async_client>(io_service);
    stp->start_connect(argv[1], argv[2]);

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran this code, then it's blocked after printed the following message:

```
$ ./async_connect www.google.com 80
try to connect to www.google.com:80
```

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks!

Comment: www.google.com has no website on port 80.  It returns a redirect to https on port 443.

Comment: it's just connect function. I can get telnet connection is working to www.google.com:80.

Comment: It should block until you send HELO, right?

Comment: I think the call to async_connect should be something like  `boost::asio::async_connect(m_socket, m_resolver.resolve(query), boost::bind(&tcp_async_client::handle_connect, shared_from_this(), _1));`.  As an aside question: why not use c++17 or 20 ??

Comment: @stark HELO? that's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: It works for me. `try to connect to www.google.com:80
success to connect`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad, I also confirmed that it's working!

Comment: Marked for close because OP explained that it is not reproducable/relevant anymore